# Tracking declarative rule condition results

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, workflow-foundation

I'm creating a custom tracking service and I need to know how I can monitor the results of declarative rule conditions in `IfElseBranchActivity`. `RuleActionTrackingEvent` only works on the PolicyActivity and I can't seem to find any example around the internet.

Thanks a lot!

Carlos

Answer (score 0):

You are correct - the RuleActionTrackingEvent is only for rules / rulesets executed via the Policy activity. There is not a tracking record emitted for the evaluation of the declarative rule condition used on the IfElse and similar activities.